# Can't resolve web-animations-js in ASP.NET Boilerplate template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I created a new project from the ASP.NET Boilerplate 3.0.0 template today (10 Oct 2017) and I ran `yarn install` in the **\angular** folder.

I then ran `npm start` and I get the error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-animations-js' in 'C:\Source\asipsa\angular\src'
resolve 'web-animations-js' in 'C:\Source\asipsa\angular\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Source\asipsa\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Source\asipsa\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The startup template is missing a dependency for web-animations-js.

To fix run `yarn add web-animations-js` and then you can run `npm start` and it will run correctly.

Comment: You may also want to uncomment this line in `angular/src/polyfills.ts`: `import 'web-animations-js';`

Comment: Then I don't need to include web-animations-js in my package?

Comment: You still need to. Including in package fixes the issue. Uncommenting allows you to leverage on it since you already included it.